# Perl: Using a hash as a reference is deprecated

Tags: perl

I'm developing script, that is reusing some really old piece of perl code.

This line gives me still the error Using a hash as a reference is deprecated .

```
  %hash->{$_[$counter]} = $_[$counter+1];
```

How I have to refactor this code, so that I will be not receiving the error.

Comment: It's also useful to know that Perl's diagnostic messages are documented in perldiag, which can be accessed here (http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) or directly on the command-line (`perldoc perldiag`).

Comment: The warning is the result of that line does not behaving as documented. The LHS of `->` should be a reference, which is a scalar, and `%hash` in scalar context shouldn't return a reference to self.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try

```
$hash{$_[$counter]} = $_[$counter+1];
```

Answer (score 24):

What's to the left of `->{` should be a hash reference, not a hash.  If you have a hash, omit the `->` and just say `$hash{`.

Pedantically, `%hash->{...}` should do what `(my $temp=%hash)->{...}` does: get the scalar value of %hash (e.g. "1/8", indicating 1 of 8 buckets used) and use that as a symbolic hash reference (failing with an error under use strict "refs").  But due to an accident, it was quietly reinterpreted as `$hash{...}` instead.
This bug will be fixed some day, but in the meantime people are being warned to change their incorrect code.