# Using an array as a reference is deprecated Error

Tags: perl

I am using 5.14.2 version of perl on Windows OS. I dont know where I am doing mistake. Please give some suggestion :

```
package  qpst_dump_collection;


use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings qw(once);
use Win32::OLE::Variant;




our $folder;
my $collectDumpsSuccess =1;
my $currentDir = 'c:';
chomp($currentDir);
my $logsPath;
my $timestamp;
our @Month_name;
my $sec;
my $min;
my $hour;
my $day;
my $month;
my $year;
my $comport;
my $comportBool = 0;
my $testcase;
$timestamp = getTimeStamp();
our $DLModem;
our $dev_id;

sub CollectDumpsIfDeviceinDownloadMode 
{
    sleep 20;
    $testcase = $ARGV[0];
    $comport = $ARGV[1];
    #$currentDir =~ s/\\/\//g;
    $timestamp = getTimeStamp();
    $logsPath = $currentDir. "/Logs";
    print "\n**************** loc is $logsPath *************************\n";
    my $prod_id = "QPSTAtmnServer.Application";
    my $qpst; 
    my $dirpath = $testcase."_"."QPSTDumps"."_".$timestamp;
    my $LogLocationPath = $logsPath."/$dirpath";
    #my $LogLocationPath = $logsPath."/QPSTDumps_$timestamp";
    my $accum = "";
    my $dir;

    # Recursively create directories
    foreach $dir (split(/\//, $logsPath))
    {
        $accum = "$accum$dir/";
        if ($dir ne "")
        {
            if(! -d "$accum")
            {
                mkdir $accum or print "Unable to create directory: $accum\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if(`adb -s $dev_id get-state` !~ m/device/i){
        print "Dumps will be stored at $LogLocationPath.................\n";
        sleep 10;
    # Attempt to use a running instance.
    eval
    {
        $qpst = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject($prod_id)
    };

    die "$prod_id not installed" if $@;

    # Start a new instance. Call Quit when $qpst set to undef or script exits.
    unless (defined $qpst)
    {
        $qpst = Win32::OLE->new($prod_id, sub {$_[0]->Quit;}) or die "Oops, cannot start $prod_id";
    }

    if (defined $qpst)
    {
        my $port = undef;
        #my $comport = "COM44";

        if ($comport eq "")
        {
            $qpst->ShowWindow();

            print "Select a phone on the GUI,\nthen return to this window and press enter to continue";
            <STDIN>;
            $port = $qpst->GetSelectedPort();
        }
        $port = $qpst->GetPort($comport);

        # Translate phone status to string.
        my %phone_status_list = qw (
        0 phoneStatusNone
        5 phoneStatusReady) ;

        if (defined $port)
        {
            $comport = $port->PortName;
            sleep(5);

            my $port_status = $port->PhoneStatus;

            if ($phone_status_list{$port_status} eq "phoneStatusReady")
            {
                my $memory_debug = $port->MemoryDebug;

                if (defined $memory_debug)
                {
                    if (!-e $LogLocationPath)
                    {
                        mkdir $LogLocationPath;
                    }

                    print "Attempting to collect dumps -- usually takes 1-3 minutes...........\n";

                    $memory_debug->{UseUnframedMemoryRead} = 1;  # boolean to tell QPST to use higher speed unframed memory reads

                    $memory_debug->SaveAllRegions($LogLocationPath);

                    if (Win32::OLE->LastError == 0) 
                    {
                        print "Dumps collected successfully..........\n";
                        $collectDumpsSuccess = 1;
                        print "Rebooting device to prepare for next iteration. Please wait 60 seconds........\n";
                        $port->Reset();
                        sleep(60);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        my $error = Win32::OLE->LastError();
                        print "Dumps were not collected successfully:\n$error\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print "No MemoryDebug interface for this port\n";
                }

                undef $memory_debug;
            }
            else
            {
                print "Phone not ready\n";
                CollectDumpsIfDeviceinDownloadMode_auto();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print "Port not available_1\n";
            CollectDumpsIfDeviceinDownloadMode_auto();
        }

        undef $port;
    }
    else
    {
        print "QPST not available\n";
    }
    undef $qpst;
    }
    else{
    print "Device detected in adb...";
    $collectDumpsSuccess = 1;
    }

}

sub CollectDumpsIfDeviceinDownloadMode_auto 
{
    sleep 20;
    #$currentDir =~ s/\\/\//g;
    $timestamp = getTimeStamp();
    $logsPath = $currentDir. "/Logs";
    print "\n**************** loc is $logsPath *************************\n";
    my $prod_id = "QPSTAtmnServer.Application";
    my $qpst; 
    my $dirpath = $testcase."_"."QPSTDumps"."_".$timestamp;
    my $LogLocationPath = $logsPath."/$dirpath";
    #my $LogLocationPath = $logsPath."/QPSTDumps_$timestamp";
    my $accum = "";
    my $dir;

    # Recursively create directories
    foreach $dir (split(/\//, $logsPath))
    {
        $accum = "$accum$dir/";
        if ($dir ne "")
        {
            if(! -d "$accum")
            {
                mkdir $accum or print "Unable to create directory: $accum\n";
            }
        }
    }

    if(`adb -s $dev_id get-state` !~ m/device/i){
        print "Dumps will be stored at $LogLocationPath.................\n";
        sleep 10;
    # Attempt to use a running instance.
    eval
    {
        $qpst = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject($prod_id)
    };

    die "$prod_id not installed" if $@;

    # Start a new instance. Call Quit when $qpst set to undef or script exits.
    unless (defined $qpst)
    {
        $qpst = Win32::OLE->new($prod_id, sub {$_[0]->Quit;}) or die "Oops, cannot start $prod_id";
    }

    if (defined $qpst)
    {
        my $port = undef;
        #my $comport = "COM44";
        my $portList = $qpst->GetPortList();
        print(" portList : $portList \n");
        my $numports = $portList->PhoneCount;
        print(" numports : $numports \n");
        for my $index (0..$numports-1) {
         my $vindex = Variant(VT_I2, $index);
         my $portname = $portList->PortName ($vindex);
         my $mode = $portList->PhoneMode ($vindex);
         print(" vindex : $vindex \n");
         print(" portname : $portname \n");
         print(" mode : $mode \n");

         if ($mode == 2) { # 4 for modeDownload, 3 for online
            print "**************Connected to COMPORT *************************\n";
            $comport = $portname;
             print(" comport : $comport \n");
         }
        } 
        if ($comport eq "")
        {
            $qpst->ShowWindow();

            print "Select a phone on the GUI,\nthen return to this window and press enter to continue";
            <STDIN>;
            $port = $qpst->GetSelectedPort();
        }
        $port = $qpst->GetPort($comport);

        # Translate phone status to string.
        my %phone_status_list = qw (
        0 phoneStatusNone
        5 phoneStatusReady) ;

        if (defined $port)
        {
            $comport = $port->PortName;
            sleep(5);

            my $port_status = $port->PhoneStatus;

            if ($phone_status_list{$port_status} eq "phoneStatusReady")
            {
                my $memory_debug = $port->MemoryDebug;

                if (defined $memory_debug)
                {
                    if (!-e $LogLocationPath)
                    {
                        mkdir $LogLocationPath;
                    }

                    print "Attempting to collect dumps -- usually takes 1-3 minutes...........\n";

                    $memory_debug->{UseUnframedMemoryRead} = 1;  # boolean to tell QPST to use higher speed unframed memory reads

                    $memory_debug->SaveAllRegions($LogLocationPath);

                    if (Win32::OLE->LastError == 0) 
                    {
                        print "Dumps collected successfully..........\n";
                        $collectDumpsSuccess = 1;
                        print "Rebooting device to prepare for next iteration. Please wait 60 seconds........\n";
                        $port->Reset();
                        sleep(60);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        my $error = Win32::OLE->LastError();
                        print "Dumps were not collected successfully:\n$error\n";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    print "No MemoryDebug interface for this port\n";
                }

                undef $memory_debug;
            }
            else
            {
                print "Phone not ready\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print "Port not available_2\n";
        }

        undef $port;
    }
    else
    {
        print "QPST not available\n";
    }
    undef $qpst;
    }
    else{
    print "Device detected in adb...";
    $collectDumpsSuccess = 1;
    }

}

sub getTimeStamp
{
    @Month_name = ( "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" );
    ($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $month, $year ) = ( localtime ) [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
    $timestamp = @Month_name->[$month]."-".$day."---".$hour.".".$min.".".$sec;
    return $timestamp;
}

1;
```

Comment: what line number did the error say?  what is on that line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl: Using a hash as a reference is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265673/perl-using-a-hash-as-a-reference-is-deprecated)

Comment: worth having a separate question for array instead of hash for searchers to find.

Comment: Are you really incapable of parsing the "question" out of the statement "I get this error from this statement."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely to be your error:

```
@Month_name->[$month]
```

should be:

```
$Month_name[$month]
```