# Perl printing rows and columns from HTML table

Tags: perl, html-table, html-tableextract

Here's my `temp.html`

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to print each element in above table using below code -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $tex = HTML::TableExtract->new(keep_html=>1);

$tex->parse_file('./temp.html');
my ($table) = $tex->tables;
#print Dumper($table);

my $numColumns = @{$table->rows->[0]};
print "\n numColumns = $numColumns\n";
my $numRows = @{$table->rows};
print "\n numRows = $numRows\n";

for my $rowIndex ( 0..$numRows-1 ) { 
    for my $columnIndex ( 0..$numColumns-1 ) { 
       print "\n row $rowIndex column $columnIndex $table->rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] ";
    }   
}
```

It prints -

```
row 0 column 0 HTML::TableExtract::Table=HASH(0x8e7d7f8)->rows->[0][0] 
row 0 column 1 HTML::TableExtract::Table=HASH(0x8e7d7f8)->rows->[0][1] 
row 1 column 0 HTML::TableExtract::Table=HASH(0x8e7d7f8)->rows->[1][0] 
row 1 column 1 HTML::TableExtract::Table=HASH(0x8e7d7f8)->rows->[1][1]
```

If I use `@{$table->rows->[$rowIndex]}->[$columnIndex]` instead of `$table->rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex]` I get correct output, but with a warning. **How to remove the warning?**

```
Using an array as a reference is deprecated at t.pl line 21.

row 0 column 0 row 1, cell 1 
row 0 column 1 row 1, cell 2 
row 1 column 0 row 2, cell 1 
row 1 column 1 row 2, cell 2
```

Comment: just a side note, you're calling same class method inside loop `$table->rows()` and it would be better to place it **outside**

Comment: @mpapec I'm sorry, din't get you. How to keep it outside? You mean by doing `my $rows = $table->rows` and then using `rows`?

Comment: `my $rows=$table->rows;` before loops and then use only `$rows`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call methods inside strings. While you can dereference variables inside strings and can access elements from hashes or arrays as well, method calls are not supported.

Instead of

```
print "... $table->rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] ";
```

You want

```
my $cell_value = $table->rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex];
print "... $cell_value ";
```

Other alternatives include using some kind of dereference. You found a solution like

```
print "... ${$table->rows->[$rowIndex]}[$columnIndex] ";
```

which works because the method call is now inside a dereferenced block, which can include arbitrary code. A more common way is to use the “shopping cart” pseudo-operator `@{[ ... ]}`, which allows interpolation of arbitrary code:

```
print "... @{[ $table->rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] ]} ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/14065917/1729501

```
@Month_name->[$month]
```

should be

```
$Month_name[$month]
```

So in my case,

```
@{$table->rows->[$rowIndex]}->[$columnIndex]
```

should be

```
${$table->rows->[$rowIndex]}[$columnIndex]
```

Comment: `$table->rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex]` is more common.

Comment: @mpapec I used it, it gave wrong result (see first output in question)

Comment: as far as I can see you've used `@{$table->..}`

Comment: @mpapec I tried 2 things in my question. Please see the code at the top. Any idea why the output is so?

Comment: you are right, `$table->rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex]` doesn't interpolate inside `""`, so you could `my $rows=$table->rows;` and then `"... $rows->[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] .."`