# Perl: Iterating over class member variables in overloaded equality sub

Tags: perl, operators, operator-overloading, equality

I'm trying to override the equality (==) operator for a class I created but I'm now facing a problem and I don't see a way out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the `new()` sub for the class:

```
sub new
{
    my $invocant = shift;
    my $class = ref($invocant) || $invocant;
    my $self = {@_};
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

Here's the equality operator overload:

```
use overload ('==' => \&compare);
sub compare
{
    my ($lhs, $rhs, $swap) = @_;
    my $lhsSize = keys(%{$lhs});
    my $rhsSize = keys(%{$rhs});
    if($lhsSize != $rhsSize) { return 0; }  # If objects don't have the same number of fields, they cannot be identical

    while (my ($lhsKey, $lhsValue) = each(%{$lhs})) # Loop through the fields
    {
        my $rhsValue = %{$rhs}->{$lhsKey};
        print("Key: $lhsKey Comparing $lhsValue with $rhsValue");
        if($rhsValue ne $lhsValue)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here I get the error `Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at Cashflow.pm line 43.` where line 43 is `my $rhsValue = %{$rhs}->{$lhsKey};`. I then found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265673/perl-using-a-hash-as-a-reference-is-deprecated) which suggest that the solution is to drop the `->` but if I change the line to `my $rhsValue = %{$rhs}{$lhsKey};` I get syntax errors.

As you may be able to tell, I'm no Perl expert, but I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Mark

Comment: FWIW, the `my $class = ref($invocant) || $invocant` technique, especially inside a constructor named "new", is considered by many to be [an unfortunate "cargo cult" practice](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=147784).

Comment: @pilcrow: As I mentioned I'm not a Perl expert so a lot of my code is derived from examples online, my only defense being my unit tests.Thanks for the tip and link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is (probably) to drop the hash dereference `%{ ... }`

```
my $rhsValue = $rhs->{$lhsKey};
```

The only reason to dereference into a hash using `%{ ... }` is if you want a list of items, such as when making a copy:

```
my %hash = %$rhs;
```

Or when using certain hash specific functions

```
keys %$rhs;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the `while` loop:

```
my $rhsValue = %{$rhs}->{$lhsKey};
```

The error is because `$rhs` is a blessed hash reference, which should be accessed like this:

```
my $rhsValue = $rhs->{$lhsKey}; # or $$rhs{$lhsKey}
```

So I would have it like this:

```
while (my ($lhsKey, $lhsValue) = each(%{$lhs})) # Loop through the fields
{
    return 0 if ! defined $rhs->{$lhsKey};

    my $rhsValue = $rhs->{$lhsKey};
    return 0 if $rhsValue ne $lhsValue;

}
```

Comment: Thanks @stevenl. I marked TLP's answer as correct because he answered first, but your comment was also very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If it's

```
%hash
$hash{$key}
```

for a hash, it's

```
%{ $hash_ref }
${ $hash_ref }{$key}
```

for a hash reference. The curlies are optional for simple reference expressions.

```
%$hash_ref
$$hash_ref{$key}
```

You can also write the latter as

```
$hash_ref->{$key}
```

`%{$rhs}->{$lhsKey}` makes no sense since there's no `%` in the hash equivalent (`$rhs{$lhsKey}`).

References:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References Quick Reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Comment: Thanks @stevenl. I marked TLP 's answer as correct because he answered first, but your comment was also very helpful. Extra thanks for the useful links that you provided alongside your answer.